# Image viewer that shows transparent as white or different color, not as checkered

Tags: png, image-viewers, gwenview

I have made a number of graphical mockups in SVG, and then exported them to PNG. They all have transparent background, because that makes sense in my case.

However, it isn't easy to browse through the PNG-files. Both Gwenview and Gnome Image Viewer (aka eog, Eye of Gnome) show the background as gray checkered. Chrome shows it how I like it, but it can't really browse through images, whereas Gwenview shows the next image on a right arrow click.

Is there an image viewer that let's me browse through SVG / PNG and show the background as fx white? Or another solution to my problem?

**Gwenview and Gnome Image Viewer**

[image]

**Chrome Browser**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps someone could create the tags: `gnome-image-viewer` and `gwenview`. I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open the <kbd>**Gnome Image Viewer**</kbd> and change the settings for <kbd>Transparent Parts</kbd>

[image]

---

And the same for <kbd>**Gwenview**</kbd>, change the settings for <kbd>Transparent Background</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Woops, really sorry I missed that. I thought I checked, but I guess I'm too tired. Well, now the question/answer is out there if other people ask. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`pqiv -c a.png`

With:

> pqiv : Powerful quick image viewer
> pqiv version 2.11 by Phillip Berndt

```
sudo apt-get install pqiv
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
pqiv --background-pattern=white a.svg
```

to show a picture that has no background with a white background instead. As mentioned above, you can install this program using

```
sudo apt-get install pqiv
```